# How to update relevant records in visual page when an button is clicked?

Tags: apex, soql, contact, field-update, popup

I created VF page which displays top 10 drivers based on thier driving efficiency(Soql query).

when the particular driver in the list clicks **HOW?**(
To tell how they achieved that position) button a pop up box opens with text area(options:Submit,Cancel)...

After typing message in that text area driver will **submit**.

The problem is:This message should be stored in particular driver contact.How to get particular driver contact id who has clicked **HOW?** button and perform update operation.

**Here is my VF page:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false"  controller="Leaderclass">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Leader Board" >
<style>
body .bPageBlock .pbBody .Grey .pbSubheader{
background-color:#c0c0c0;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.customPopup {
background-color: white;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
left: 40%;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
/* These are the 3 css properties you will need to tweak so the pop 
up displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can also add 
the height property for a fixed size pop up.*/
width: 500px;
top: 20%;
}

.disabledTextBox {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid;
color: black;
cursor: default;
width: 90px;
display: table;
padding: 2px 1px;
text-align:right;
}   

.closeButton {
float: right;
}
</style>

<apex:outputPanel styleClass="Grey " layout="block">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Top 10 Leaders"  >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapper}"   var="a" id="table" >
<apex:column headervalue="DriverName" >{!a.Dname}</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Average Efficiency" >{!a.Deffi}</apex:column>
<apex:column headervalue="Badge" > 
<apex:image value="{!If((a.Deffi >0 && a.Deffi <4), $Resource.Diamond, 
If((a.Deffi >= 4 && a.Deffi <5), $Resource.Platinum,
If((a.Deffi >= 5 && a.Deffi <6), $Resource.Gold,
If((a.Deffi >= 6 && a.Deffi <8), $Resource.silver,
If((a.Deffi >8), $Resource.StopDriving,
$Resource.StartDriving)))))}" width="50" height="50" />
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="User Stories">
<apex:commandButton value="HOW?" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="status"  onmouseover="openPopup();" /></apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="popup">
<apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
</apex:commandButton>
<apex:pageblockSection >                         
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Story" for="story"></apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputTextArea cols="60" rows="3" />
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
</apex:pageblockSection>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
</apex:commandButton>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Page:**

```
public with sharing class Leaderclass{
public Leaderclass() {

}
public Leaderclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
}
public String showPopup { get; set; }
public String Story{get;set;} // input text1 value  from vf
List<DriverEfficiency__c> e= new List<DriverEfficiency__c>();
List<AggregateResult> a=new List<AggregateResult>();
public List<wrapper> w= new List<wrapper>();
public List<wrapper> getwrapper() {
a= [select DriverContact__r.name Dname ,avg(Efficiency_Rating__c) from DriverEfficiency__c GROUP BY DriverContact__r.name order by avg(Efficiency_Rating__c) asc  limit 10];
for (AggregateResult SalesList : a) {
w.add(new wrapper(String.valueOf(SalesList.get('Dname')), Double.valueOf(SalesList.get('expr0'))));
}
return w;
}


// Wrapper Class Construction
public class wrapper{
public String Dname{get;set;}
public Double Deffi{get;set;}

// Wrapper class constructor
public wrapper(String Dname,Double Deffi){
this.Dname=Dname;
this.Deffi=Deffi;
}
}

public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}
public void showPopup()
{
displayPopup = true;
}

public void closePopup() {
displayPopup = false;
}
private  contact myContact;
public PageReference redirectPopup()
{
displayPopup = false;
//PageReference p=new Pagereference('/'+'apex'+'/'+'Wrapper');
myContact = [SELECT Id, Name FROM contact
WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
myContact.StoreImageUrl__c=Story;
update myContact;
return null;
//p.setRedirect(true);
//return p;
}
}
```

Please help me...Thanks in advance for your kindly help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapper}"   var="a" id="table" >
...
    <apex:commandButton onclick="showPopup({!a.dId})" ...>
...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
...
<apex:actionFunction name="showPopup" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="...">
    <apex:param name="driverId" assignTo="{!driverId}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

In controller you have to add property

```
public String driverId {get;set;}
```

And you can use this value in submit method. Also you need add dId (driver id, I think) in your wrapper and soql.